Win32 FILE_BASIC_INFORMATION.*Time.QuadPart - which value should be used if filesystem doess not support it?
The Win32 FILE_BASIC_INFORMATION structure defines four time values:
LARGE_INTEGER CreationTime;
LARGE_INTEGER LastAccessTime;
LARGE_INTEGER LastWriteTime;
LARGE_INTEGER ChangeTime;

How can a filesystem indicate if it does not support a particular timestamp, such as ChangeTime? Should ChangeTime.QuadPart then be -1, -2 or 0, or another value?

I can't find any definitive info on what the value should be when querying the timestamps. When saving the timestamps, -1 and 0 are equivalent to ignore the value at the time of saving, and -2 only applies to NTFS and ReFS to restore a cached timestamp. So, I'm guessing the answer to your question is probably either -1 or 0.

filesystems usually first zero init FILE_BASIC_INFORMATION and then init members from it internal structures. so if some value not supported, it will be 0. of course possible do some tests, create temp file or use some existing, set values (say to current time) and then check it back. are it returned the same as was set or 0/-1. here question - for what is this need ? in practic you can compare value with 0 - if it <= 0 - value is not supported. if it > 0 - supported
